# Textbox user input restriction

Tags: asp.net, html

I use `onkeypress="return this.value.length"` that working fine. but i do copy and paste it keep  on putting data in the text box. it should work for copy-paste operation too.

what i need to do for copy-paste operation to work for that too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to limit what characters can be entered into a text box, you may find that the AjaxControlToolKit can help.  It has a control called Filtered Textbox contro.  Take a look at http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx

Comment: yes exactly i was looking for that! but how i use that as to restrict user to enter specific number of character? i search on that but not find!

Comment: This can be done without any extenders or javascript.  If you are using ASP.Net, just set the max length, like this:  <asp:TextBox Text="some text" ID="myId" runat="server" MaxLength="5" ></asp:TextBox>

Comment: but in the case of multiline text box. which become textarea when render on server. and html textarea does not support max length. then what should i do??? is filtered textbox give me the solution? actually "onkeypress=return this.value.length < 80"  works fine but not work for copy-paste operation. its keep pasting even characters exceed from 80.

Comment: I'm not sure if the filtered textbox extender can limit the size.  You can also try RegularExpressionValidator control:  http://forums.asp.net/t/1170096.aspx/2/10

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to find length while typing

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="alert(this.value.length)" / >
```

Hope it helps !! :)

Answer (score 0):

use `onchange` with `onkeypress`. so that whatever you have put there also executes on change

Answer (score 0):

I think `ontextchanged=""` could cover it